# Table width not 100% of div inside foundation column

Tags: width, zurb-foundation, css-tables

I have run into the problem where the width of a table, that should be 100% of it's parent div, is a few pixels short, when using foundation 5.

This is the CSS used, except for Foundation standards:

```
.headline {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}
.table-wrap {
  padding: 0;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;

}
```

An example can be seen here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fEkrc

How would I go about making sure the table is 100% width of its column?

Comment: this is happening because of the `width 100%` value rounded differs by `0.6px` between `column` and table wrap. check with large-7 columns both get rounded off to 408 px. which dosent give 1 px difference.

Comment: It still gives the difference for me with large-7 columns, but you are right about the 0.6px. The question remains though, is there anyway to make sure that the table is the same size as the column while keeping the layout fluid?

Comment: try margin-right: -1px; not a clean fix though.if you dont get a better solution use this

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using padding:0px !important; margin: 0px !important;? maybe there's a problem in the hierarchy of the css, with !important you can overrun such problems

Comment: The table is still 1px less wide than it's parent.

Comment: Does the parent have any padding or margin?

Comment: No, nothing. Take a look at the codepen. I believe the problem might have something to do with the rendering of tables, not padding or margin

Comment: I looked at the codepen and i found the problem, the width:100%; is not on the same parent, headline and table both have the same parents:
.large-12 and .columns (in this case neighter are used in the CSS), the one parent that is being eddited in the css is the one that is not common... 
what i did to try is change <div class="large-8 columns">
to <div class="large-8 columns hello">, then in the css give .hello a width of 400, this creates a common parent, and makes it even, I HAVE NO IDEA why it didn't work before, but this seems like a fine workaround

Comment: The problem with that is that the parent cannot have a fixed width, since it's a fluid layout.

Comment: @RubyvanSoelen That should be a comment because it is a suggestion not an answer..If they did work when you try it in fiddle he gave..You should have posted as an answer..